# Why does for-loop code break after first iteration?

Tags: r, for-loop

```
Nums <- c(1:30)

for (i in 1:30) {
  if (Nums[i] %% 2 == 0 & Nums[i] %% 3 != 0) {
    Nums[i] <- c("ok")
  }
}

Nums
```

I am an Window 10, R 4.1.2 user.
I want to replace vectors in `Nums` with `"ok"` but results are like this...

```
Error in Nums[i]%%2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

```
> Nums
 [1] "1"  "ok" "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
[11] "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "20"
[21] "21" "22" "23" "24" "25" "26" "27" "28" "29" "30"
```

Why does for code operate only once?

Comment: Your are coercing your vector to be character when assinging "OK", therefore you can't apply `%%` on a character value. That's why your loop doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your desired result without using the for loop:

```
Nums[Nums %% 2 == 0 & Nums %% 3 != 0] <- "OK"
```